# Time complexity of binary search in a slightly unbalanced binary tree

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search-tree

The best case running time for binary search is O(log(n)), if the binary tree is balanced. The worst case would be, if the binary tree is so unbalanced, that it basically represents a linked list. In that case the running time of a binary search would be O(n).

However, what if the tree is only slightly unbalanced, as is teh case for this tree:

[image: Lets take this binary tree for example.]

Best case would still be O(log n) if I am not mistaken. But what would be the worst case?

Comment: For that tree all case are O(1). You need to specify a formula for the tree depth in terms of n, or provide an algorithm whose complexity can be analyzed to produce a complexity formula in terms of n.

Comment: The worst case would still be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when we say something like "the cost of looking up an element in a balanced binary search tree is O(log n)," what we mean is "*in the worst case*, we have to do O(log n) work in the course of performing a search on a balanced binary search tree." And since we're talking about big-O notation here, the previous statement is meant to be taken about *balanced trees in general* rather than a specific concrete tree.

If you have a specific BST in mind, you can work out the maximum number of comparisons required to find any element. Just find the deepest node in the tree, then imagine searching for a value that's bigger than that value but smaller than the next value in the tree. That will cause you to walk all the way down the tree as deeply as possible, making the maximum number of comparisons possible (specifically, h + 1 of them, where h is the height of the tree).

To be able to talk about the big-O cost of performing lookups in a tree, you'd need to talk about a *family* of trees of different numbers of nodes. You could imagine "kinda balanced" trees whose depth is Θ(√n), for example, where lookups would take time O(√n), for example. However, it's uncommon to encounter trees like that in practice, since generally you'd either (1) have a totally imbalanced tree or (2) use some sort of balanced tree that would prevent the height from getting that high.

Answer (score 0):

In a sorted array of **n** values, the run-time of binary search for a value, is 
`O(log n)`, in the **worst case**.
 In the **best case**, the element you are searching for, is in the **exact middle**, and it can finish up in constant-time.
 In the **average case** too, the run-time is `O(log n)`.